# Get Id User in codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, web, database-connection

i have two database. tabel_jawaban and tabel_user.

in tabel_user there is field called "id_user"

i want to move/call "**id_user from tabel_user**" to "**id_user in tabel_jawaban**" when registration.

but i failed. anyone can help? there are my code....

model_user :

```html
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class Model_user extends CI_Model {
  function __construct() { 
  parent::__construct();
  $this->tbl = "tabel_user";
  } 
  
  function cek_user($username="",$password="") {
  $query = $this->db->get_where($this->tbl,array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
  $query = $query->result_array();
  return $query;
  }
  
  function ambil_user($username)
  {
        $query = $this->db->get_where($this->tbl, array('username' => $username));
        $query = $query->result_array();
        if($query){
            return $query[0];
        }
  }
  
  function ambil_iduser($idUser)
  {
        $query = $this->db->get_where($this->tbl, array('id_user' => $idUser));
        $query = $query->result_array();
        if($query){
            return $query[0];
        }
  }
  
  function getAllUser() {
  $this->db->from('tabel_user');
  return $this->db->get();
  }
  
  function deleteUser($id)
  {
  $this->db->where('id_user', $id);
        $this->db->delete('tabel_user'); 
  }

 }

?>
```

Jawaban_model:

```html
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Jawaban_model extends Ci_Model {

  public function Ambil() {
    $data = $this->db->query('select * from tabel_jawaban, tabel_user where tabel_jawaban.id_user=tabel_user.id_user');
    return $data;
  }

  public function AmbilNilai2($iduser) {
    $data = $this->db->query("select * from tabel_jawaban, tabel_user where tabel_jawaban.id_user=tabel_user.id_user AND tabel_jawaban.id_user='$iduser'");
    return $data;
  }

  public function Simpan($tabel, $data){
    $res = $this->db->insert($tabel, $data);
    return $res;
  }

  public function UpdateTotalNilai($id_jawaban,$data)
  {
    $this->db->where('id_jawaban',$id_jawaban);
    $this->db->update('tabel_jawaban',$data);

  }
}
```

Controller :

```html
function daftar(){
  $ambil_akun = $this->session->userdata('uname');
        $idUser = $this->user_model->AmbilIdUser($ambil_akun);

  $data = array(   
   'id_user' => $idUser,
   'tgl_tes' => date("Y-m-d"),
  );

  $this->jawaban_model->Simpan('tabel_jawaban', $data);
  $id=mysql_insert_id();  

  redirect('dashboard/soaluser/'.$id);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is minor typo in your code. As far as I could notice, your `user_model->` method is

```
function ambil_iduser($idUser)
        {
        $query = $this->db->get_where($this->tbl, array('id_user' => $idUser));
        $query = $query->result_array();
        if($query){
            return $query[0];
        }
```

Whereas, in your controller, you are calling for different method here,

```
 $idUser = $this->user_model->AmbilIdUser($ambil_akun);
```

Both the method's name differs `ambil_iduser` and `AmbilIdUser`.

The correct controller calling state should be

```
function daftar(){
        $ambil_akun = $this->session->userdata('uname');
        $idUser = $this->user_model->ambil_iduser($ambil_akun);

        $data = array(          
            'id_user' => $idUser,
            'tgl_tes' => date("Y-m-d"),
        ...
```